# Must a War Weaver make a touch attack to target friends with touch spells at range using Enlarged Tapestry?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, touch-attacks

War Weaver (*Heroes of Battle*, p. 112) gives a spellcaster the ability to cast harmless touch spells at range, via the **Enlarged Tapestry** class feature:

> At 5th level, you can stretch your magic across your eldritch tapestry beyond normal distances. Spells you cast through an eldritch tapestry have their range category increased: touch spells become close range, close-range spells become medium range, and medium-range spells become long range. Long-range spells and spells with fixed ranges are unaffected.

Normally, you don't have to make attack rolls to target friends with touch spells.  From [the SRD](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/actionsInCombat.htm#touchSpellsinCombat):

> You can automatically touch one friend or use the spell on yourself, but to touch an opponent, you must succeed on an attack roll.

Enlarged Tapestry doesn't say anything explicitly about changing this rule, but there's obviously a sense in which, once you're casting something at range, it's no longer a touch spell, so perhaps the above doesn't apply.

The most analogous case elsewhere in the rules, the Reach Spell metamagic feat (*Complete Divine*, p. 84), *does* require attack rolls on spells it has modified to have range longer than touch:

> You may cast a spell that normally has a range of touch at any distance up to 30 feet. The spell effectively becomes a ray, so you must succeed on a ranged touch attack to bestow the spell upon the recipient. A reach spell uses up a spell slot two levels higher than the spell's actual level.

...but of course, Enlarged Tapestry lacks that "effectively becomes a ray" verbiage, so perhaps it's not *really* analogous.

---

**If I'm a War Weaver casting a touch spell at longer-than-touch range on an ally via Enlarged Tapestry, do I need to make a touch attack roll to do so?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, unlike Reach Spell (and the archmage’s arcane reach high arcana), enlarged tapestry does not change a touch attack into a ray (or non-ray touch attack spell, since those are things). Instead, it changes the spell into a Close-range spell, just an ordinary single-target or multi-target spell. Normally this sort of thing would add a saving throw, but since spell cast into the tapestry must be harmless anyway, there isn’t much point so they don’t bother.